# How to not make if statements "link up" with an else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm making a simple program to ask you if you want pizza:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
{
    char answer;
    cout << "Yes or no, would you like some pizza?: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    if ((answer == 'n') || (answer == 'N')) {
        cout << "Have some anyway.";
    }
    if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y')) {
        cout << "Okay, here's your pizza!";
    }
    else {
    cout << "Huh? Give me a proper answer.";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you type in "Yeah" or anything starting with a Y it returns "Here's your pizza". The problem is if you type anything starting with a n, it says "Have some anyway" AND "Huh? Give me a proper answer".

I've tried to replace the else statement with another "if" that went

```
    if ((answer != 'n') || (answer !='N')) {
    cout << "Give me a proper answer";
}
```

and did that for each letter in that if-statement but the same problem occurs... help?

Comment: `if (a) { A } else if (b) { B } else if (c) { C } else { D }`

Answer (score 4):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char answer;
    cout << "Yes or no, would you like some pizza?: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    if ((answer == 'n') || (answer == 'N')) {
        cout << "Have some anyway.";
    }
    else if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y')) {
        cout << "Okay, here's your pizza!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Huh? Give me a proper answer.";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What happened before, is that the following code was executed even if `((answer == 'n') || (answer == 'N'))` was true:

```
if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y')) {
    cout << "Okay, here's your pizza!";
}
else {
cout << "Huh? Give me a proper answer.";
}
```

...which is why we had to write `else if` instead of `if`, so that the above code is only executed when `((answer == 'n') || (answer == 'N'))` is false.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what was wrong and how it was fixed.

Comment: @anatolyg : fixed, thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

Use `else if` instead of second `if`

```
if ((answer == 'n') || (answer == 'N')) {
    cout << "Have some anyway.";
}
else if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y')) {
    cout << "Okay, here's your pizza!";
}
else {
cout << "Huh? Give me a proper answer.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition == true) {/*do this*/}
else if (other_condition == true) {/*do that*/} //repeat as much as you like
else {/*do other stuff*/}
```

Or use a switch statement:

```
switch(answer) {
case 'y': case 'Y': /*do this*/ break;
case 'n': case 'N': /*do that*/ break;
/*do other stuff*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using else if in the second if statement...like

```
else if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y')) {
        cout << "Okay, here's your pizza!";
    }
```

everything else is fine